# Is Yoda around during The Old Republic?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-the-old-republic

I have been playing the *Star Wars: The Old Republic* game and I was wondering if Yoda was alive during this time frame; was he born yet or what?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars%3a_The_Old_Republic) says the game takes place more than 3,500 years prior to the *Star Wars* films.  Given that

> when 900 years old you reach, look as good you will not

Yoda won't be born until roughly 2,600 years after the *Star Wars: The Old Republic*.

Comment: ok, thanks I just was asked several times by people and wanted to give them a definet answer

Comment: Seemingly, no one seems to know what race Yoda is, even though there is another Jedi Master of Yoda's race in SW:KOTOR

Comment: I have not yet met him. Where is he, and what story do you have to play?

Comment: Telos, mission deck. Taral V mission. He is a Young looking Fellow. http://swtor.wikia.com/wiki/Oteg